# AndroidX Camera How to zoom on a targeted Area

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm using `androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.3` camera library and I want to add to zoom the camera preview In which section Pinch to zoom initiate, Like if I initiate pinch in center of the preview it should zoom center part of preview and if I initiate pinch to zoom at top right corner it should apply zoom on top right corner. In current Implementation If I initiate pinch to zoom at any section of screen it apply zoom from center of the preview.

Hope My question is clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported by CameraX on its own, because zooming is generally implemented in the Android device's camera device itself.  And basically all devices only support center-zoom.

You could implement off-center zoom yourself in the GPU, but it won't be as good quality. The main reason you want the device to do the zoom is because usually the preview output is far lower resolution than the image sensor's full resolution.  So as you zoom in, you just scale down less, instead of upscaling the output ~1080p resolution to something blurry.

So you'd want some kind of combination of device zoom and GPU cropping.

Comment: Can you share some example or a snippet that how to achieve this with GPU. Thanx